# NiFi ExecuteSQL Processor psql UPDATE ERROR: index out of range

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-nifi

The content claim of my flowfile is formatted as hex and retains the following:

```
UPDATE tx_well_logs_tests SET file_type=TIFF, file_name=4205936720_295ft_4195ft_resistivity_30347115-d336-45fc-bf1d-4a06a8930e54.tiff, id=QQRio80yU54. WHERE api_num=123 AND doc_id=009;
```

**Note** that in the corresponding psql table, *ALL* fields are of `TEXT` PostgreSQL data type.

After formatting this statement with...

```
UPDATE tx_well_logs_tests SET file_type='TIFF', file_name='4205936720_295ft_4195ft_resistivity_30347115-d336-45fc-bf1d-4a06a8930e54.tiff', id='QQRio80yU54.' WHERE api_num='0123' AND doc_id='009';
```

...and directly pasting it into my console for testing, the statement execute successfully and the table is updated accordingly. However, when I incorporate the *exact* same statement into the content claim of a given flowfile, the following NiFi error is thrown:
[image]

Even though the values are different for this image example and field values are not quoted as strings, this error still persists even when they are.

Here is the format of the ExecuteSQL processor:
[image]

This error is likely resulting from the psql driver. What is a possible strategy to resolve this error?

### ===**EDIT & UPDATE 1**===

Using the PutSQL processor, here is my configuration:
[image]
The processor *BEFORE* the PutSQL stage is a ReplaceText processor that generates the following PostgreSQL statement - this resides in the content claim of a given flowfile:

```
UPDATE public.tx_well_logs_tests SET file_type='TIFF', file_name='4236733992_9380ft_10294ft_resistivity_30347115-d336-45fc-bf1d-4a06a8930e54.tiff', id='XB5HOxVsI-M.' WHERE api_num='4236733992' AND doc_id='XB5HOxVsI-M.';
```

This statement has - again - been checked by successfully executing on the console.
With all that has been changed so far, what occurs is the following:
[image]
Here is the error thrown - the same as before:
[image]
Errors are thrown - however - the processor continues to run with 
nothing occuring (i.e. no fails, retries, or successes). What may be causing this and how can it be resolved?

===**EDIT & UPDATE 2**===

The following is the declaration of my PostgreSQL (driver version: 42.2.5) table:

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table tx_well_logs_tests
(
  district           text,
  field_num          text,
  field_name         text,
  oil_lease_gas_id   text,
  lease_name         text,
  api_num            text not null,
  op_name            text,
  well_num           text,
  county_name        text,
  copy_to_public     text,
  county_num         text,
  survey_name        text,
  survey_sec_num     text,
  alt_survey_name    text,
  abstract_num       text,
  block              text,
  file_type          text,
  ogd_code           text,
  top_log_interval   text,
  bottom_total_depth text,
  doc_date           text,
  image_size         text,
  scan_date          text,
  log_desc           text,
  add_notes          text,
  doc_id             text,
  add_notes2         text,
  file_name          text,
  id                 text
);

comment on table tx_well_logs_tests is 'test table for NiFi workflow for finding all APIs for TX well-logs and extracting their corresponding log files (LAS,TIFF)';

alter table tx_well_logs_tests
  owner to sw_admin;

create unique index tx_well_logs_testing_api_num_doc_date_top_log_interval_bottom_t
  on tx_well_logs_tests (api_num, doc_date, doc_id);
```

Also, note the info below relates to the attributes of a given flowfile:

```
Connection
close
Content-Length
622
Content-Type
text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date
Fri, 10 Jan 2020 22:15:24 GMT
NeuESD
NeuAuth=b17224eb980f067f810b9d1d27b74716; expires=Fri, 10-Jan-2020 21:15:18 GMT}
RouteOnAttribute.Route
wlt_t_1
Server
Apache
Set-Cookie
NeuAuth=997378eaf4050f205ca62f22b4f6bff9; expires=Fri, 10-Jan-2020 23:15:24 GMT; path=/; secure; httponly
Transfer-Encoding
chunked
X-Frame-Options
SAMEORIGIN
api_key
publicuser
api_number
25534770
api_sig
68461babf138014f252e64732ef3b1a0
clean_download_file_name
Urrutia Unit 7H_5 inch MD.tif
docId
tENr9IxMDZA.
download_file_name
["Urrutia Unit 7H_5 inch MD.tif"]
file_type
TIFF
file_url
api.php?function=GetAttachment&profile=15&id=4KhrLTrgv50.&docid=ScvjoBtDIS4.
filename
2bcd7862-e9e5-48f3-9a4d-967c65b9c61e
fragment.count
2
fragment.identifier
7692ab1b-ce5b-4bd8-8cc1-0e1804995880
fragment.index
1
fragment.size
2
invokehttp.remote.dn
CN=*.neubus.com,OU=Domain Control Validated
invokehttp.request.url
https://rrcsearch3.neubus.com/esd3-rrc/api.php?function=GetMiscDoc&json=%7B%22Neusearch%22%3A%7B%22profile%22%3A15%2C%22miscDocID%22%3A%22ScvjoBtDIS4.%22%7D%7D&_=1576167190746
invokehttp.status.code
200
invokehttp.status.message
OK
invokehttp.tx.id
f0a529c7-de12-4fb2-9882-515881790323
mime.type
text/html; charset=UTF-8
mod_file_name
4225534770_gammaray.tiff
path
./
record.count
1
segment.original.filename
2bcd7862-e9e5-48f3-9a4d-967c65b9c61e
sql.args.1.type
12
sql.args.1.value
02
sql.args.10.type
12
sql.args.10.value
Empty string set
sql.args.11.type
12
sql.args.11.value
255
sql.args.12.type
12
sql.args.12.value
EBERLY, J
sql.args.13.type
12
sql.args.13.value
Empty string set
sql.args.14.type
12
sql.args.14.value
Empty string set
sql.args.15.type
12
sql.args.15.value
102
sql.args.16.type
12
sql.args.16.value
Empty string set
sql.args.17.type
12
sql.args.17.value
G
sql.args.18.type
12
sql.args.18.value
11500
sql.args.19.type
12
sql.args.19.value
18456
sql.args.2.type
12
sql.args.2.value
86950600
sql.args.20.type
12
sql.args.20.value
2018-11-20
sql.args.21.type
12
sql.args.21.value
0.44 MB
sql.args.22.type
12
sql.args.22.value
2018-11-20
sql.args.23.type
12
sql.args.23.value
Gamma Ray
sql.args.24.type
12
sql.args.24.value
note
sql.args.25.type
12
sql.args.25.value
TMMB9GMS8mc.
sql.args.26.type
12
sql.args.26.value
W|
sql.args.3.type
12
sql.args.3.value
SUGARKANE (EAGLE FORD)
sql.args.4.type
12
sql.args.4.value
280336
sql.args.5.type
12
sql.args.5.value
URRUTIA UNIT
sql.args.6.type
12
sql.args.6.value
4225534770
sql.args.7.type
12
sql.args.7.value
MARATHON OIL EF LLC
sql.args.8.type
12
sql.args.8.value
7H
sql.args.9.type
12
sql.args.9.value
KARNES
sql.table
tx_well_logs_tests
text.line.count
1
uuid
b9785d94-de78-4f8a-bcc6-86a4f8e58d5b
well_log_id
ScvjoBtDIS4.
```

**===Final Update===**

The following attribute and psql statement resulted in a successful update:

```
UPDATE public.tx_well_logs_tests SET file_type='TIFF', file_name='4228533979_measurewhiledrillingmwd.tiff', id='mf3w9o9Lu3g.' WHERE doc_id='dsqlC9svY5Y.';
```

---

```
Content-Type
ASCII
Date
Fri, 10 Jan 2020 22:16:21 GMT
docId
Kfm4wvs8F-U.
download_file_name
["tif_1"]
executesql.row.count
0
No value set
file_type
TIFF
file_url
api.php?function=GetAttachment&profile=15&id=lq0k4PAnT1E.&docid=NIou2oGtv7A.
filename
2bcd7862-e9e5-48f3-9a4d-967c65b9c61e
invokehttp.remote.dn
CN=*.neubus.com,OU=Domain Control Validated
invokehttp.request.url
https://rrcsearch3.neubus.com/esd3-rrc/api.php?function=GetMiscDoc&json=%7B%22Neusearch%22%3A%7B%22profile%22%3A15%2C%22miscDocID%22%3A%22NIou2oGtv7A.%22%7D%7D&_=1576167190746
invokehttp.status.code
200
invokehttp.status.message
OK
invokehttp.tx.id
440ddb70-3da6-4fee-8c7c-e32a7db0c2d6
mime.type
application/avro-binary
text/plain (previous)
mod_file_name
4239133071_combinationresistivityneutrondensityporosity.tiff
NeuESD
NeuAuth=b17224eb980f067f810b9d1d27b74716; expires=Fri, 10-Jan-2020 21:15:18 GMT}
path
./
RouteOnAttribute.Route
wlt_t_5
Server
Apache
Set-Cookie
NeuAuth=ed268e82101f228c0a773531e19b4277; expires=Fri, 10-Jan-2020 23:16:21 GMT; path=/; secure; httponly
Transfer-Encoding
chunked
uuid
2e165d14-8a4a-4a55-bfd2-9e51da78dc2b
well_log_id
NIou2oGtv7A.
X-Frame-Options
SAMEORIGIN
```

I'm not sure why this worked, but it does not with no problems.

Comment: Does PutSQL work instead? It uses a different JDBC call to execute the statement rather than a "query", and since yours is an UPDATE it shouldn't return a ResultSet, so you shouldn't need ExecuteSQL when PutSQL should work. If it doesn't please let me know and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @mattyb. I've incorporated some edits for the question to help show what is and what is not working.

Comment: Can you share your table definition? Since you're not using a PreparedStatement per se (with `?` for column values) then I wouldn't think NiFi would know anything about column indexes...

Comment: Yes, I've included edit and more info in Part 2 of this question (at bottom)